# java regex can't use symbol ? and {n} together

Tags: java, regex

I would like to write regex that match string with follow rules:

1. At first and last position can be symbols `a-z` `A-Z` or `0-9` but not `.` or `-`
2. Hole length of string 16 characters
   [image]
3. In the middle can exists symbols `a-z` `A-Z` `0-9` `-` `.` Symbol `.` and symbol `-` are not required. Correct combinations for symbol `.` and '-' in the middle:
   no exists `.` and `-` (aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa)
   exists one `.` (aaaaaaaaaa.aaaaa) or any position except first and last
   exists one `-` (aaaaa-aaaaaaaaaa) or any position except first and last
   exists two `.` and `-` (aaaaaaa-.aaaaaaa) or any position except first and last

I don't need java code only working regex.
I tried write something like this `^[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d\.-]{14}[a-zA-Z\d]$`. But this regex has a problem: in the middle(hole string without first and last character) can exists symbols `.` `-` not once. For example `dfdsfdsfdsfd..dd` `dfdsfdsfdsf...dd` `dfdsfd--dsfd..dd` are correct strings for my expression. Hope I exactly explain what I need :)

Comment: So, they are incorrect?

Comment: _"But symbol . and symbol - can exists or not"_ -- This is not clear.  Can you provide some examples of some _invalid_ strings?

Comment: @JimGarrison All this string incorrect: dfdsfdsfdsfd..dd   dfdsfdsfdsf...dd    dfdsfd--dsfd..dd because they contains more than one symbol . and -. But this string correct: dfdsfdsfdsfd99dd  dfdsfdsfds.dhhdd   dfdsfdsfds-djjdd dfdsfdsfdsfd.-dd

Comment: So a string is incorrect only if there are two or more dots or two or more hyphens? Then `dfdsfdsfd--sf.dd` must be failed.

Comment: @stribizhev Yes, the string fdsfdsfd--sf.dd must be failed. You understood me right but one remark: symbol . and - can't be at first and last positions

Comment: Could you edit your question and add (in a clear way please) examples of allowed strings and forbidden strings.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Please see my edited questions

Comment: @fidel150992: I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex that will disallow more than 1 hyphen or dot in the string:

```
^(?!(?:.*-){2}|(?:.*\.){2})[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d.-]{14}[a-zA-Z\d]$
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mV6mS3/8)

This pattern also disallows `.` and `-` in the initial and final positions as the first and last character class do not allow them.

Comment: In your example this string are correct but must be incorrect dfdsfdsfdsf.d.dd    dfdsfdsfdsf-.-dd   df.sfdffdsfd..dd

Comment: Ah, I see your comment

Comment: In another demo these strings incorrect: dfdsfdsfd--sf.dd
dfdsfd--dsfdd.dd .

Comment: If I am correct, I undelete my answer. As you said, `dfdsfdsfd--sf.dd` and `dfdsfd--dsfdd.dd` are incorrect, so they are not matched.

Comment: Sorry, I've mistaken. You are right this regex what I need. Actually you answer and Casimir's answer are correct. But your answer for me more pretty because your pattern check everything itself(don't need checking str.length())

Answer (score 1):

Use `\p{Alnum}++(?>\.\p{Alnum}*-?\p{Alnum}+|-\p{Alnum}*\.?\p{Alnum}+)?` with the `matches` method and test the length of the string with `str.length() == 16`.

```
if (str.length == 16 && str.matches("\\p{Alnum}++(?>\\.\\p{Alnum}*-?\\p{Alnum}+|-\\p{Alnum}*\\.?\\p{Alnum}+)?")) {
    ...
```

Note that if the length is not 16, the regex isn't tested at all.

```php
\p{Alnum}++
(?>            # open an atomic group
    \.         # a literal dot
    \p{Alnum}* # zero or more alphanumeric characters
    -?         # an optional hyphen
    \p{Alnum}+ # one or more alphanumeric characters
  | # OR the same in a different order
    -\p{Alnum}*\.?\p{Alnum}+
)? # the atomic group is optional
```

Comment: your answer is right but I check stribizhev answer as correct because he don't use java for checking length of string(str.length()). Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: @fidel150992: If I test the length outside of the pattern and before the pattern, it is because a regex has a cost, and `str.length == 16` when it fails avoid this cost. Note too that the string is parsed only once since lookarounds are not used.

Answer (score 0):

To require that there be exactly one dot/dash, use a look ahead:

```
"^(?=[^-.]*[-.][^-.]*$)[a-zA-Z\\d][a-zA-Z\\d.-]{14}[a-zA-Z\\d]$";
```

Note:

- you don't need to escape a dot within a character class
- you don't need to escape a dash within a character class, if it's the first or last character (you already had this)

---

Some test code:

```
String regex = "^(?=[^-.]*[-.][^-.]*$)[a-zA-Z\\d][a-zA-Z\\d.-]{14}[a-zA-Z\\d]$";
Stream.of("okdsfdsfdsfd.ddd","okdsfdsfdsfd-ddd","dfdsfdsfdsfd..dd", "dfdsfdsfdsf...dd", "dfdsfd--dsfd..dd", "aaaabbbbccccdddd", ".123456789012345")
        .forEach(s -> System.out.println(s + " " + s.matches(regex)));
```

Output:

```
okdsfdsfdsfd.ddd true
okdsfdsfdsfd-ddd true
dfdsfdsfdsfd..dd false
dfdsfdsfdsf...dd false
dfdsfd--dsfd..dd false
aaaabbbbccccdddd false
.123456789012345 false
```